# how to edit different axis manually in matlab's figure?

Tags: matlab, axes

I am using a plotyy in matlab to ploy two data set in a same figure. I want to use the figure menu to edit the axes property manually. But I found that I can only select and edit the first axis but not the second one. Of course, I can edit those with command 'set' but just wonder how to select the second axis.

Comment: I've run into that before.  If I recall correctly you can access the second axis by selecting and moving/stretching the top one.  (edit) Although now that I try it, that doesn't seem to work with plotyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your figure, click "View -> Plot Browser", the second axis will be listed at the bottom and can be selected.